# testing jQuery show(), hide() with Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, selenium-ide

I have a Javascript application that sends a request to yahoo Maps API and toggles a div tag's display with jQuery show() or hide() depending on the result.

I'm trying to write a test in [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) that will check the css display attribute of my div.

I understand the [waitForCondition](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/waitForCondition) command but I'm having trouble working out how to check the above condition. I don't think Selenium IDE has jQuery built into it so I think my options are plain old javascript (shown in the previous link) or something like xPAth.

Can anyone give me some pointers? Is my question clear enough?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I used the code below in a waitForCondition to wait till a dynamic element was changed from display: none to display : block, shouldn't be hard to adapt it too your needs:

```
selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementById('articleDetails').style.display == 'block'
```